# How to check that nginx not work with certificate?

Tags: windows, nginx, ssl

On `Windows` machine i got `IIS` and `nginx 1.12`.
Admin give me `.key` and `.crt` files. And i see that `IIS` works fine with it and provide access to site via `https`.
Now i am trying to add SSL to `nginx` with this certificate:

```
server {
    listen 8081 default_server;
    listen [::]:8081 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name xn--80afgznagjs.xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai;
    keepalive_timeout   60;

    ssl_certificate     "C:/xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "C:/xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.key";
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
}
```

But i cant access to nginx via https.
I checked certificate:

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\openssl.exe" x509 -noout -subject -in C:\\xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai.crt
```

And see:

```
CN = *.xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai
```

So all subdomains included. What can i miss?

Comment: actual error messages would be helpful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider In browser i jsut got `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider How can i check it?

Comment: Open your firewall configuration and check if the port you are trying to reach is allowed. I can't be more specific since I don't know what you are using.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It is really was firewall issue. I just open port and all starts to work. But why IIS works fine without opened port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection timeout usually (in 99.9% of all cases, vague estimate from experience) points toward a firewall issue. Check that the port you are trying to reach is open in all firewalls between you and your server.

---

Addressing your comment: I assume the firewall responsible was the Windows Firewall directly on your server. In this case, Windows knows that IIS is installed and is running and automatically opens all ports the IIS executable binds to.

Answer (score -1):

Not a win master but check your cert path

`"C:/xn--80acgfbsl1azdqr.xn--p1ai.crt";`

Shouldnt it be with backslash?

Comment: that's a valid notation. If the certificate file hadn't been found nginx wouldn't even start in the first place.